# Not able to make GridView in Android

Tags: android, gridview, layout-inflater

I am trying to make a GridView app just like I made the custom ListView where I have used the BaseAdapter.

But in this GridView `Mainactivity.java`, in the class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter unable to return `images.length`, where images is an integer array where I have taken all the required images in it.

Also I am unable to use `getLayoutInflater()`, it is showing cannot resolve method `getLayoutInflater()`;

below i have attached a screenshot where you can see that i am trying to return the length but it shows error, similarly the layout inflator

[Showing error in line 39][1]

[Showing error in line 59][2]

Below are the code snippets.

Mainactivity.java

```
class customadapter extends BaseAdapter {

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    // Everytime the user wants to display one item to the user, it simply calls the
    //getview method , specifies the position of the item
    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
    return null;
}
```

}

Please open the below link for code snippet snapshots

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY8uR.jpg

Comment: your are not setting any data (images) to adapter, so it will not work.  go and check it her https://stackoverflow.com/a/20347155/3983054

Answer (score 0):

you have to do change in your `custom.xml` 
In this your Both `LinerLayout` with `width` `wrap_content` and `height` is `wrap_content`.

you have to `inflate` Layout Like below in Adapter.

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom, parent, false);
```

Comment: i changed it.. but still i get error in mainactivity.java showing that images.length is not valid(in red color)

Comment: Also, how changing the height and width is related to getview and inflater?

Comment: after proper inflate layout you can get image.length property.

Comment: Nope. the actual problem is QS not setted any data to custom adapter and he simply sets a empty adapter.

Comment: in mcontext what should i keep? and also in parent should i keep i ??

Comment: @KingofMasses , i am about to set the data, but still images.length is not working, that is y i have stopped there

Comment: what u mean by image.length not working ? have u tried to making your custom adapter class public ?

Comment: @KingofMasses below is the screenshot when i tried to make the class public its showin this
http://imgur.com/a/MAvPZ

Comment: Please help in this issue, i am stuck for so much time

Comment: @KingofMasses sorry, i missed class, now i wrote public class
http://imgur.com/a/ERezM

Comment: check my answer and let me know if you stil facing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set images in adapter as well as set layout properly as already answered

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
  {



int[] images =
        {R.drawable.Harvey, R.drawable.Litt,R.drawable.Mike,R.drawable.harvey,
                R.drawable.mark_wahlberg
        , R.drawable.oliver};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView  gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid1);

    customadapter adapter = new customadapter(images);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

this will help i guess.

```
 class customadapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

      private int[] images;

        public customadapter(int[] images) {
            this.images = images;
        }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return  images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        // Everytime the user wants to display one item to the user, it simply calls the
        //getview method , specifies the position of the item
        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom,null);
        return null;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this ,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
  {


Integer[] images =
        {R.drawable.Harvey, R.drawable.Litt,R.drawable.Mike,R.drawable.harvey,
                R.drawable.mark_wahlberg
        , R.drawable.oliver};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView  gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid1);

     gridView.setAdapter(new CustomGridAdapter(this, images));
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}

 // Here is your custom Adapter

    public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Activity mContext;

        // Keep all Images in array
        public Integer[] mThumbIds;

        // Constructor
        public CustomGridAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, Integer[] items) {
            this.mContext = mainActivity;
            this.mThumbIds = items;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mThumbIds[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
            return imageView;
        }

    }
}
```